# Which Qt5 modules are enabled by default?

Tags: c++, qt, build, qt5, qmake

I'm on my way to build Qt from source, downloaded http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.9/5.9.8/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.8.tar.xz and there README at some point says:

> The above examples will build whatever Qt5 modules have been enabled
>   by default in the build system.

Which modules have been enabled by default?

Comment: I think by default all modules are enabled, if the dependencies are met. If you run configure you will be presented with a list of the enabled modules.

Comment: it will tell you when you run e.g. `configure -platform win32-g++ -opensource -confirm-license`